# System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Tags: c#, database-connection

Today when i ran my c sharp project in visual studio i got this error

> "System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll" The
>   underlying provider failed on Open.

While few days before it was working well, Here is my code in which it is giving error.
Anyone please help me.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.HeaderCell.Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1;

            label2.Text = "";
            dbcontext = new BookDatabase.BooksEntities();
            var bookName = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
            var book = from bok in dbcontext.Books
                       where bok.Title == bookName
                       select bok;
            foreach (var bk in book)//Showing problem here, highlighting book
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = bk.Code;
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = bk.Edition;
                var auto = from autho in bk.Authors
                          select autho;
               foreach (var author in auto)
                    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = author.FirstName + " " + author.LastName;

                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = bk.Price;
           }
        }
```

Comment: When i got it, that was because proper credentials were not being used to open the connection. Check the principal/identity that is trying to open the connection and if that has the privileges of opening that connection.

Answer (score 0):

Does it provide an inner exception? It is usually more specific. Verify that your database server is online and that your connection string is correct.